# Access denied during Google Family Link account login

Tags: google-signin

Is there a way to customize Google login error?

My users receive a bad access_denied error trying to login into my webapp using a **Google Family Link Account**.

I know that parents should configure Family Link, setting my webapp as secure for their child but the login error is very criptically for average users.

It's something like this:

> Error 403: access_denied
>
> Details:
>
> redirect_uri: ...
>
> response_type: permission id_token
>
> openid.realm=
>
> ...

Comment: duolingo.com has the same error. I assume this is related to family link?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it seems a Google side error. Sadly nothing is changed after many months.

Comment: I suspect duolingo.com (and likely your app as well) are asking for user permissions that google refuses to grant to accounts linked to kids <13 years old. Probably related to COPA? Perhaps personal details like name, age, location, etc.?

Comment: Seems correct. Unfortunately there's nothing in the API that would seem to allow for determining the underlying reason in this case: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same problem after introducing subscriptions.

Comment: @tobinharris I haven't the problem anymore. It was probably a Google side error.
I don't use subscriptions. Sorry.